# Build UI Similar to "Voice Memo" app? Referring to the "Voice Graph"

Tags: swift

For the past 2 weeks iv been searching all kinds of tutorial stops to give me hints on how to build a UI similar to "Voice Memo" app on the iOS.

My problem is Im not sure exactly how to approach building this piece..specifically that "vocal graph/bar system" at the top of the app.

Heres what Im talking about - https://i.stack.imgur.com/igGSv.jpg

Im somewhat experienced in Swift Animations but I have no idea how to build that "Vocal Chart" on the image.

Could anyone tell me some areas I should look into to start learning how to build that component?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find anything ?